# Syntax of Split control

Tags: vb.net, split, char

I have ported an application from .NET Core to .NET Framework and it seems to go fine for everything, except a line where I have to split a string in order to fill a table with it. Then I have to erase all the spaces except one so I wrote:

```
Dim item() As String = line.Trim.Split(" "c, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

In NET Core no errors where found. Here I have the following error:

```
Error   BC30518 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Split' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Overloads Function Split(ParamArray separator As Char()) As String()': Value of type 'StringSplitOptions' cannot be converted to 'Char'.
    'Public Overloads Function Split(separator As Char(), count As Integer) As String()': Value of type 'Char' cannot be converted to 'Char()'.
    'Public Overloads Function Split(separator As Char(), options As StringSplitOptions) As String()': Value of type 'Char' cannot be converted to 'Char()'.
    'Public Overloads Function Split(separator As String(), options As StringSplitOptions) As String()': Value of type 'Char' cannot be converted to 'String()'.    FDS2Ansys   C:\Users\Nicola\source\repos\FDS2Ansys\FDS2Ansys\Form2.vb   113 Active
```

I think that I have to express the space `" "c` as a char but I haven't understand how. Does anyone could help me solving this issue? Thanks a lot all are gonna answer me. Best regards.

Comment: Look at the error message. It tells you exactly what overloads of `Split` are available and your c all does match any of them. You are passing one `Char` argument and one ``StringSplitOptions` argument. None of the four overloads have that signature. Look at the signatures of the overloads and pass arguments that match.

Comment: Change `" "c` to `" ".ToCharArray()`.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Probably better to change it to `{" "}` or `{" "c}`.

Comment: As @Idle_Mind suggested, it works properly. Thanks for the support!

Comment: @Craig If you're going to label it "better", then at explain why it's "better"?  For multiple delimiters, I like to type `" ,-".ToCharArray()` versus `{" "c, ","c, "-"c}`.  IMHO, the first is easier to read.  Take the three characters in the string and turn them into a character array...

Comment: @Idle_Mind For that case, I can see it, though I might still favor the explicit array form.  For a single delimiter, though, I think `ToCharArray()` is overly wordy without any useful gain in understanding.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Split` expects char array or string array as first parameter, you should change your code as follows:

```
Dim item() As String = line.Trim.Split(" ".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```